# C++ Class.function syntax without initializing the class (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

This is a very beginner question so please don't judge me too harshly. In C++, specifically on the Arduino platform although I doubt that makes a difference, I often use libraries that go like so:

```
#include "WiFi.h"

...
Serial.println("Supra");
WiFi.begin(MODE);
...
```

But I have never initialized these classes, but they seem to act like singletons. I looked for source that might shed some light but I didn't find anything.

How are these classes initialized? How would I make my own, for example called `Messenger` that would be accessible by just including its header file and then have the variable name `Messenger` with functions like `Messenger.send`?

Comment: Please add the source code link in your question.

Comment: What you can do is just check the WiFi.h interface and see the definition of those WiFi.begin and you can follow similar way to create your own Messenger.send.

Comment: They "act like singletons" because they are global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `WiFi.h` header in arduino-esp32 master branch:

```
class WiFiClass : public WiFiGenericClass, public WiFiSTAClass, public WiFiScanClass, public WiFiAPClass
{
// ...
};

// here global variable of class WiFiClass is defined
extern WiFiClass WiFi;
```

Now, when you execute `WiFi.begin(whatever)` you are invoking `begin` method from `WiFiSTAClass` that `WiFiClass` inherits.

From `WiFiSTA.h` :

```
class WiFiSTAClass
{
public:

    wl_status_t begin(const char* ssid, const char *passphrase = NULL, int32_t channel = 0, const uint8_t* bssid = NULL, bool connect = true);
    wl_status_t begin(char* ssid, char *passphrase = NULL, int32_t channel = 0, const uint8_t* bssid = NULL, bool connect = true);
wl_status_t begin();

// ...
```

If you would like to create your own class and a global variable of this class in the header, just create a header e.g. `Myheader.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
// MyHeader.hpp
class Messenger {
public:
    bool send() {
        // whatever
        return true;
    }
};

extern Messenger Msngr;
```

However, I strongly discourage you to follow this pattern. Using global variables is quite bad for many reasons. If for some reason you wish to avoid copying the objects of your class, just use smart pointers. If for some reason you wish the objects of your class to be created somewhere else, just create a Factory that will return the desired instances.